# how to separate the array by key and value in php

Tags: php, arrays

***My Array***

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ProductInfo] => Prouduct 1  [Dept] => 01 [MarkOnTimeShipment] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [ProductInfo] => Prouduct 2 [MarkOnTimeShipment] => 0 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [ProductInfo] => Prouduct 2 [MarkOnTimeShipment] => 1 )  [3] => stdClass Object ( [ProductInfo] => Prouduct 2 [MarkOnTimeShipment] => 0 )  [4] => stdClass Object ( [ProductInfo] => Prouduct 2 [MarkOnTimeShipment] => 1 )
```

I have some array like above now what i'm trying to get is there are two values like below. I need to separate it and make it as array

***Exptected output***

***MarkOnTimeShipment = 1*** is an septrated array

```
  Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ProductInfo] => Prouduct 1  [Dept] => 01 [MarkOnTimeShipment] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [ProductInfo] => Prouduct 2 [MarkOnTimeShipment] => 0 )    [2] => stdClass Object ( [ProductInfo] => Prouduct 2 [MarkOnTimeShipment] => 1 )
```

***MarkOnTimeShipment = 0***  is an septrated array

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ProductInfo] => Prouduct 1  [Dept] => 01 [MarkOnTimeShipment] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [ProductInfo] => Prouduct 2 [MarkOnTimeShipment] => 0 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the array by **MarkOnTimeShipment** key as

```
$newArr = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $newArr[$value->MarkOnTimeShipment][] = $value;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);

$array1 = $newArr[0]; // MarkOnTimeShipment = 0 
$array2 = $newArr[1]; // MarkOnTimeShipment = 1
```

**Result of $array1 (MarkOnTimeShipment = 0):**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ProductInfo] => Prouduct 1
            [Dept] => 1
            [MarkOnTimeShipment] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ProductInfo] => Prouduct 3
            [MarkOnTimeShipment] => 0
        )

)
```

**Result of $array2 (MarkOnTimeShipment = 1):**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ProductInfo] => Prouduct 2
            [MarkOnTimeShipment] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ProductInfo] => Prouduct 4
            [MarkOnTimeShipment] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different function available for keys and values array_keys and array_values. Please try it.

```
$array_keys = array_keys($array);
$array_values = array_values($array);
```

Comment: Can you please come back with my expected ouput